# Spring Security 3 custom remember me

Tags: spring-security

i want to change remember me request parameter to override default parameter '_spring_security_remember_me'
and custom my remember me service to replace `<remember-me />` namespace config.

so i config my remember me service:

```
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <property name="key" value="MY_REMEMBER_ME_KEY" />
    <property name="cookieName" value="MY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE" />
    <property name="parameter" value="remember" />
    <property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="1209600" />
    <property name="useSecureCookie" value="true" />
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <property name="alwaysRemember" value="false" />
</bean>
```

namespace config:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/secure/index" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>
```

when i run application and login. i find cookie is created then i close my ie and reopen.
entry the path '/secure/index', tomcat show me access is denied .
but i revert to Spring Security default config , all is ok.

i debug code find

```
RememberMeAuthenticationFilter#doFilter
...
Authentication rememberMeAuth = rememberMeServices.autoLogin(request, response);
...
//autoLogin(request, response) method code.
String rememberMeCookie = extractRememberMeCookie(request);
...
protected String extractRememberMeCookie(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

    if ((cookies == null) || (cookies.length == 0)) {
        return null;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        if (cookieName.equals(cookies[i].getName())) {
            return cookies[i].getValue();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

in method `extractRememberMeCookie(request)`, code `request.getCookies()` always return null when i use my custom remember me service, but i revert Spring Security default namespace `<remember-me/>` and do the same(clean Cookies - login - close ie - reopen - entry path '/secure/index'), i also find cookie is create . 
and i debug the code i find `request.getCookies()` return the cookie name 'SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE' and authentication successfully.

need other config to remember me authentication ? 
but i don't know , would someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<remember-me />` still need key

this should be

```
<remember-me key="MY_REMEMBER_ME_KEY" services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [TokenBasedRememberMeServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html),

> An [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) is
>   required by this implementation, so that it can construct a valid
>   Authentication from the returned
>   org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails. This is
>   also necessary so that the user's password is available and can be
>   checked as part of the encoded cookie.

Perhaps your configuration is incorrect/incomplete.

Comment: thanks Raghuram . but i don't konw why request.getCookies() always return null. if null Could not Authentica .

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an old post. But I just had the issue `request.getCookies()` null w/ Spring 4.

I've removed `useSecureCookie = true` to fix it.